# How to replace centered brand text in Navbar with a centered brand image in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: svg, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, centering

I am trying to build a navbar in bootstrap 3 with a centered logo. The logo is a .svg file. I don't know how to exchange it for the "brand" text while allowing it to stay centered. Maybe someone out there has an idea. Let me know if there is anything you guys need!

I'm using this online svg logo as an example of what I want to do because I couldn't figure out how to do my logo on jsfiddle. They used an svg html tag. I don't know exactly what the benefits of this are, but it is in the example, so be aware.

The important part is the css. This is what makes the navbar center, when most navbars in bootstrap are floated left or right. Here is the css.

```
.navbar-brand {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}
```

The text/logo fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12577/

The fiddle with the SVG:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12578/